# Scrolling issue with Canvas style.left/top

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am making a magnifying glass for a canvas application but ive run into an issue with scrolling.
Essentially the goal is to take a canvas and when an image is added (in this case a cgm image) and make a snapshot of it, scale it up and draw it on to a second smaller canvas that overlays it and follow the mouse (preferably a drag/mousedown and up, but i am using mousemove for testing purposes). I believe the issue is in the zoom.style.top & zoom.style.left NOTE on my main aplication I have a top margin of 70px so keep that in mind.

here is a quick example I wrote up

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var ox = canvas.width / 2;
var oy = canvas.height / 2;
ctx.font = "42px serif";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.fillRect(ox / 2, oy / 2, ox, oy);
function magnify() {
  var main = document.getElementById("canvas1");
  var ctx = main.getContext('2d')
  var base64 = main.toDataURL('image/png', 0);
  drawing = new Image();
  drawing.onload = () => {
    var zoom = document.getElementById("tCanvas");
    var zoomCtx = zoom.getContext('2d');
    zoomCtx.drawImage(drawing, 0, 0);
  }
  main.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    var zoom = document.getElementById("tCanvas");
    var zoomCtx = zoom.getContext('2d');

    zoomCtx.clearRect(0, 0, zoom.width, zoom.height);

    zoomCtx.drawImage(main, e.x, e.y, 200, 200, 0, 0, 300, 300);
    zoom.style.top = e.pageY - 70 + "px"
    zoom.style.left = e.pageX - 10 + "px"
    e.pageY = -150
    e.pageX = -150
    zoom.style.display = "block";
  });

  main.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
    var zoom = document.getElementById("tCanvas");
    zoom.style.display = "none";
  });
  drawing.src = base64;
};
```

```html
<canvas id="tCanvas" class="cgm" height="100" width="100" style="background-color:white;  position: absolute; display: none; z- 
      index:1;border:1px solid red;">  </canvas>
<canvas tabindex=1 class="cgm" id="canvas1" style="position:relative;  background:white; 
      left:0;right:0;margin:auto;z-index:1;margin-top:70px;  "></canvas>
<p></p>
<button id="zoom" onclick="magnify();">Zoom</button>
```

Here's a fiddle for reference (I fixed the height to display the scroll issue).

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qLf0nxkz/)

Comment: You say 'scrolling issue' but while looking at your sample I couldn't really see what you mean by that. Could you clarify what the actual issue is?

Comment: Can you explain what is the purpose of the variable `drawing` you draw one time from it but later on the `mousemove` are using the "main" canvas to draw, seems that variable is not really needed

Comment: How about the `e.pageY = -150` what is that doing?

Comment: From the JSFiddle the canvas on top ("tCanvas") prevents the mouse move events on the background canvas... is that what you mean by an issue with scrolling??  the solution for that is to add this to your top canvas: `pointer-events: none;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified a lot of the code on your JSFiddle.

See if this is the behavior you are looking for:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const zoom = document.getElementById("tCanvas");
const zoomCtx = zoom.getContext('2d');

for (let i = 10; i < 20; i++)
  for (let j = -60; j < 800; j += 60)
    ctx.fillText(j + i, i * 20 - 180, i * 9 + j);

function getMousePos(evt) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
  return {
    x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
    y: evt.clientY - rect.top
  }
}

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  zoomCtx.clearRect(0, 0, zoom.width, zoom.height);
  let pos = getMousePos(e)
  zoomCtx.drawImage(canvas, pos.x, pos.y, 200, 200, 0, 0, 300, 300);
  zoom.style.top = e.pageY - 10 + "px"
  zoom.style.left = e.pageX - 10 + "px"
  zoom.style.display = "block";
});

canvas.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
  zoom.style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
#tCanvas {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #808080;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#canvas1 {
  background-color: #808080;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="tCanvas" width=100 height=100></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas1" width=240 height=800></canvas>
```

I think that your issue was with `pointer-events: none;` the top canvas was preventing the events from reaching the bottom canvas.

Also you don't have to declare your `document.getElementById("..` on every function, those should be global constants

For the issue with a long canvas we need to use `canvas.getBoundingClientRect` in the calculation to get the real position of the mouse in the canvas

Comment: Close! I appreciate the code tidying. Unfortunately it seems the scroll issue is still there. I made a Js fiddle of your example with a bigger height to show you what i mean. https://jsfiddle.net/vhec4bqj/1/

Comment: I think I see the problem, I scroll down and it still shows the magnified top not the area I'm pointing at

Comment: @MatthewWithington take a look at my latest code, and here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/heldersepu/xj7u0p1n/12/